# Issue with SCSS and SCOUT

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, scout-sass

I'm using SCOUT to compile my SCSS files to CSS.

I have the following code:

```
$header-background: #ddd;
$header-font-size: 12px;

.header {
    background-color: $header-background;
    font-size: $header-font-size;

    &__logo {
        border: solid 1px #000;

        &--link {
        }

        &--image {
        }
    }

    &__banner {

        &--link {
        }

        &--image {
        }
    }
    .navigation {

        &__mobile {

            &--button {
            }

            &--link {
            }
        }

        &__menu {

            &--list {
            }

            &--item {
            }

            &--selected {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm saving the file I'm getting the following error on SCOUT:

> error webstyle.scss (Line 7 of _header.scss: Invalid CSS after "  &": expected "{", was "-logo {"
>   "-logo" may only be used at the beginning of a selector.) Sass::SyntaxError on line 7 of C: Invalid CSS after " &": expected "{", was "-logo {"
>   "-logo" may only be used at the beginning of a selector.

I'm using the latest SCOUT version.

When I'm running the same SCSS in "codepen" it's working well and compiled good (http://codepen.io/chaofix/pen/RNRzym)

What could be the reason for that? Why I can't compiled with SCOUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Scout uses Compass 0.12 and Sass 3.2.  The features you're attempting to use require Sass 3.3.

https://github.com/scout-app/scout-app/issues/185

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Scout-App supports this feature.

- http://Scout-App.io